# VsCode Stuck and Close Automatically

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code

I'm using Ubuntu 22.02 operating system and do coding in VS Code. I'm facing the problem that when I code HTML or CSS my VsCode works well but when I code JavaScript or ReactJS or React Native, after writing some lines of code my VsCode gets stuck and everything stops working and after 1 or 2 Minutes VsCode closes automatically.

Do you have an idea what's wrong?